# What's the deal with MSVCR DLL?

Tags: windows, dll

What is it for ?

Why are their various versions of it ? What are the available versions and what each of them match what ?

Why it seems to cause licence problems ? E.G : I some tools such as py2exe can't bundle them but you still need them to run the resulting exe.

How to solve that if you want to distribute a software for Windows :

- technically : how to make sure the user has one ? If not how to provide one ? For all version of Windows.
- legally : does it work the same for free software ? For profit software ? Is there something specific to do ?

Comment: you need to read Microsoft's license and documentation to understand the redistribution parameters.

Comment: This is like answering "read the doc" or "google it", which is NOT welcomed on SO.

Comment: Legal questions are off-topic here, so a comment is the best you can expect.

Comment: Fair enough, I should move this part to a more appropriate Q/A plateform. The rest remains.

Comment: You can't distribute microsoft crt dll by copying them but you are welcome to give the Microsoft distributable package with your product. Microsoft can update those dll for bug or security reasons but I've never see something broken because of this.

Comment: Link is helpful:: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the C runtime that's used by Windows executables.  Which were written in C or C++ so they have a C runtime requirement like any C or C++ program.

It is a private DLL, to be used *only* by Windows executables.  You cannot distribute it or overwrite it, that would be rather disastrous.  The DLL is protected by the Windows File System Protection feature, overwriting it will get it to automatically restore the file again.

You should not take a dependency on it, Microsoft has no obligation to keep it compatible between Windows versions.  That did however not slow down the MinGW project, they use it anyway.  Or it can be an issue if you use a very old version of Visual Studio whose CRT also used that name, an issue with the 15 year old version 6.  YMMV if you ended up having a dependency on it.

Comment: If I want to distribute a py2exe bunddle software, I do have a dependancy on it.

Comment: You don't.  It is pretty explicit in the [tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step5), you have a dependency on msvcr71.dll or msvcr90.dll.  Those are distinct versions and not the same as msvcrt.dll

Comment: Ok, I got that part wrong. My question are bout msvcr, indeed. I didn't know they was a msvcrt as well. My mistake.

Comment: You cannot assume the user already has a copy, you must deploy it yourself.  And it is not free software, you must own a license to Visual Studio to get the right to redistribute the DLL.  Any version will do, including the free Express edition afaik.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime. They match the compiler versions.

You can link against it statically, which removes the dependency. Your install could detect if your user needs it.

Comment: Not my vote, but didn't MS remove the static option recently? My recollection is that as of vs2010, there are no more /mt/ml, only /md/mdd, so no static linking.

Comment: @bmargulies your question isn't clear.

Comment: @bmargulies it exists. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(v=vs.100).aspx